# Creating custom scrollbar in IE

Tags: css, scrollbar

I am trying to create a custom scrollbar, I managed it to work on Chrome, Opera, and Firefox. However, I am struggling to make it work on IE. Below is my code I use

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.50em;
    height: 2em

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background: green;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background: blue;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red;

}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using a 3rd party library (or at least taking some inspiration from one), here are some examples

- http://learnboost.github.io/antiscroll/
- http://charuru.github.io/lionbars/
- http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/